# Planner Plan get ID

Tags: php, microsoft-graph-api, office365

I'm trying to get all the plans in a group and then their buckets and tasks.
I'm using PHP and the Graph SDK

I can get the plans in a group like this:

```
 $plans = $this->graph->createCollectionRequest('GET', '/groups/'.$groupId.'/planner/plans')->setReturnType(Model\PlannerPlan::class)
            ->execute();
```

Now I want to get the buckets, but that call requires the plan ID. and the plan ID is a protected member of Model\PlannerPlan::class.

The Model\PlannerPlan->getBuckets() does nothing but return a null.

(getTitle() works by the way, so I'm doing something right.)

I'm obviously misunderstanding something here.

How can I get the buckets:

```
GET /planner/plans/{plan-id}/buckets
```

from an instance of a PlannerPlan?

Comment: Maybe your plan just does not have buckets? I mean, "getBuckets()" sounds reasonable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call `Model\PlannerPlan->getId()`.

[getId](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-php/blob/dev/src/Model/Entity.php#L64) is `public`.

Comment: DOH! it is inside Entity, didn't think about that. Thank you
I still don't understand the point of the function inside the PlannerPlan class like getBuckets() though. I mean how would it get the data?